# unique_ptr swap doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++11, swap, unique-ptr

My code is:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Core{
    Core(int n){} };

int main() {
    int base;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Core>> cores;

    cores.push_back( std::move(std::unique_ptr<Core>(new Core(base))) );
    cores[0].swap(std::unique_ptr<Core>(new Core(base)));

    return 0;
}
```

And I get this error:

> ||=== Build: Release in Test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>
> In function 'int main()' error: no matching function for call to 'std::unique_ptr<Core>::swap(std::unique_ptr<Core>)'
>
> note: candidate is:
>
> note: void std::unique_ptr<_Tp,_Dp>::swap(std::unique_ptr<_Tp,_Dp>&) [with_Tp = Core; _Dp = std::default_delete<Core>]
>
> note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::unique_ptr<Core>' to 'std::unique_ptr<Core>&'

Comment: FYI: Your code has undefined behavior on account of accessing the uninitialized `int base`. Also, the initial push-back is overkill to perform `std::move`

Comment: Why are you trying to swap into a temporary? The signature of `unique_ptr::swap` does not allow this.

Comment: I want to change the content of what's inside my vector[0], but I don't know how to, I thought of using a swap and  let the temporary die at the end of scope

Comment: My version of gcc is more user friendly: `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::unique_ptr<Core>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::unique_ptr<Core>’`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not swap with a temporary object (an `rvalue`) like this:

```
cores[0].swap(std::unique_ptr<Core>(new Core(base))); // error
```

But a temporary can swap with a named object (`lvalue`) like this

```
std::unique_ptr<Core>(new Core(base)).swap(cores[0]); // but this works
```

Alternatively you can just set the value directly:

```
cores[0] = std::unique_ptr<Core>(new Core(base));
```

Or (better) using [std::make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)

```
cores[0] = std::make_unique<Core>(base);
```

You pass the parameters for the object's constructor directly to the `std::make_unique` function.

And if you must use `new` there is always the [std::unique_ptr::reset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) function:

```
cores[0].reset(new Core(base));
```

Comment: Second code fragment is the obvious answer for the correct/easiest way to swap. This should be accepted imho.

Also everyone simplifies his push_back statement, which wasn't part of the question, but doesn't mention the even more simple emplace_back(new Core(base));

Comment: @lars `emplace_back(new Core(base))` leaks in case vector resize throws.

Comment: if I try to assign cores[0], I get this `error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Core; _Dp = std::default_delete<Core>]'|`

Comment: @Sheed Did you do it the same way I did it here? You can only assign a temporary like that, not a named object. If you want to assign a named object then you have to use `std::move()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `std::move` too much. In your cases, the move happens automatically. So, you can just write

```
cores.push_back( std::unique_ptr<Core>(new Core(base)) );
cores[0] = std::unique_ptr<Core>(new Core(base));
```

Or, using `std::make_unique` and `std::unique_ptr::reset`,

```
cores.push_back( std::make_unique<Core>(base) );
cores[0].reset(new Core(base));
```

If, however, you had your `unique_ptr`, say, as a local variable, you'd have to use `std::move`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Core> p(new Core(base));
cores.push_back(std::move(p));
```

This is as efficient as the above, but creates a potentially needless local variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need an lvalue `std::unique_ptr<Core>` to swap with, an unnamed temporary isn't allowed.

What you can do is

```
cores.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Core>(new Core(base))); // don't need move here
{
    std::unique_ptr<Core> other(new Core(base));
    cores[0].swap(other);
}
```

Comment: is there another more efficient way to change the content of one of my vector's element? I'm using swap as an alternative but is it really good?

Comment: This uses the same overload of `vector<...>::push_back`. The `move` does *nothing*